# Linker Error on cross compiling Project in eclipse

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, arm, cross-compiling

In my project I am using cross tool-chain `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux` with symbol `arm-linux-gnueabihf-`; it compiled properly but giving Linker error.

While same project is been compiled by `Linux GCC`; there'll be no such type of errors, smoothly binary is been generated.

```
Building target: PM100_IEC61850_FW
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  -o "PM100_IEC61850_FW"  ./Util/BlockFifo.o ./Util/ByteBuffer.o ./Util/ChecksummedFile.o ./Util/CircularBuffer.o ./Util/CwiDateTime.o ./Util/FileMap.o ./Util/PactDateTime.o ./Util/Stream.o ./Util/TimeInterval.o ./Util/Util.o ./Util/crc.o  ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSConfigData.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSDataAccess.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSDataParam.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSLocalData.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSMakeMap.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSObjTable.o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSTestSource\ .o ./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMS_Main.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/xml/file_root.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/xml/filesys.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/xml/xml.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/tase2/tase2api.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tase2/tase2hand.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tase2/vendhand.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam_task/tam_task.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam_task/waittask.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/linux_se.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/tam.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/tam_con.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/tam_tp.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/timefunc.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/tam/uca_time.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/stack/stack.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/simulate/controls_sim.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/rtg/rtg.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/rfc1006/cfg1006.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/rfc1006/rfc1006.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/casm.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/cbuff.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/dlsm.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/emitfetc.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/error.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/evalfunc.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/files.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/ioroutin.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/jour_if.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/mmsdecod.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/mmstypes.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/search.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/service.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/utility.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/cscl_lex.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/cscl_tab.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/d2t_tab.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/gom_dir.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/prs_tab.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/t2d_lex.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/t2d_tab.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/tase2_objs.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/make7/yys_tab.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/dt/data_cfg.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/dt/dt_io.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/dt/dt_list.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/dt/lexyy.o  ./TMW-61850-Shared/cscl/scl_ext.o ./TMW-61850-Shared/cscl/scl_rtg.o  ./Storage/ReaderFile.o ./Storage/TimestampedRecordFile.o  ./RulesHandler/Action.o ./RulesHandler/LevelEntryRule.o ./RulesHandler/LevelExitRule.o ./RulesHandler/LogEventAction.o ./RulesHandler/MultiPhaseRule.o ./RulesHandler/MultiPhaseState.o ./RulesHandler/QuantityLogAction.o ./RulesHandler/Rule.o ./RulesHandler/RulesCollection.o ./RulesHandler/SingleQuantityRule.o ./RulesHandler/StateRuleFactory.o ./RulesHandler/TestAction.o  ./RevenueEvents/CTMissEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/CTOpenEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/CTReversalEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/CTShortEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/CurrentUnbalanceEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/EventConfiguration.o ./RevenueEvents/EventDetector.o ./RevenueEvents/FeederSupplyFailEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/InvalidPhaseAssociationEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/InvalidVoltageEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/MagnetInterferanceEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/NeutralDisturbanceEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/OverVoltageEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/PTMissEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/PowerSupplyOffEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/RevenueEventCollection.o ./RevenueEvents/RevenueEventLog.o ./RevenueEvents/UnderVoltageEvent.o ./RevenueEvents/VoltageUnbalanceEvent.o  ./ModbusClient/ModbusClient.o ./ModbusClient/SerialUART.o  ./Modbus/ModbusCoilCollection.o ./Modbus/ModbusCommLog.o ./Modbus/ModbusDevice.o ./Modbus/ModbusMaster.o ./Modbus/ModbusPDU.o ./Modbus/ModbusRTUADU.o ./Modbus/ModbusRTUTransport.o ./Modbus/ModbusRegisterCollection.o ./Modbus/ModbusSerialCounters.o ./Modbus/ModbusSlave.o ./Modbus/ModbusTCPADU.o ./Modbus/ModbusTCPTransport.o  ./Logging/CaptureLog.o ./Logging/EnergyBuffer.o ./Logging/EventLog.o ./Logging/Log.o ./Logging/LogManager.o ./Logging/QuantityLog.o ./Logging/QuantityLogCollection.o ./Logging/SampleLog.o ./Logging/TimebasedLog.o ./Logging/TimebasedLogCollection.o ./Logging/ValueCollection.o  ./HAL/Debug.o ./HAL/LinuxCommPortDriver.o ./HAL/LinuxCriticalSection.o ./HAL/LinuxDisplayDevice.o ./HAL/LinuxETHDevice.o ./HAL/LinuxEvent.o ./HAL/LinuxFileStorage.o ./HAL/LinuxFileStorageRAM.o ./HAL/LinuxLocalServer.o ./HAL/LinuxMailBox.o ./HAL/LinuxMessageQueue.o ./HAL/LinuxNetServer.o ./HAL/LinuxProgramInfo.o ./HAL/LinuxRTCDevice.o ./HAL/LinuxTask.o ./HAL/LinuxTimer.o ./HAL/cwi_malloc.o  ./Expat/xmlparse.o ./Expat/xmlrole.o ./Expat/xmltok.o ./Expat/xmltok_impl.o ./Expat/xmltok_ns.o  ./EnergyMetering/EnergyHandler.o ./EnergyMetering/HistoryCollection.o ./EnergyMetering/MDRegisters.o ./EnergyMetering/RateRegisters.o ./EnergyMetering/TariffApplication.o ./EnergyMetering/TariffStructure.o  ./DataCollector/Aggregator.o ./DataCollector/DataCache.o ./DataCollector/DataCollector.o ./DataCollector/MeterNodeCommunicator.o ./DataCollector/PersistedCircBuf.o ./DataCollector/SampleBuffer.o ./DataCollector/SampleSet.o  ./DLMS/AES.o ./DLMS/Association.o ./DLMS/COSEM.o ./DLMS/COSEMUtils.o ./DLMS/DLMSInstr.o ./DLMS/DLMSServer.o ./DLMS/DLMSSysVars.o ./DLMS/EEPROM.o ./DLMS/HDLC.o ./DLMS/OBIS.o ./DLMS/UtilsByteOps.o  ./ConfigController/ConfigController.o ./ConfigController/ConfigData.o ./ConfigController/Flextend.o  ./CalculatedValues/Accumulator.o ./CalculatedValues/AccumulatorCollection.o ./CalculatedValues/DeadbandValue.o ./CalculatedValues/DeadbandValueCollection.o ./CalculatedValues/FlickerStatistics.o ./CalculatedValues/FlickerStatisticsCollection.o  ./ApplicationEngine/ApplicationEngine.o ./ApplicationEngine/Display.o ./ApplicationEngine/LocalProcessDataprovider.o ./ApplicationEngine/MeterFacade.o ./ApplicationEngine/ModbusSlaveClient.o ./ApplicationEngine/QuantDefCollection.o ./ApplicationEngine/QuantityDefinition.o ./ApplicationEngine/Settings.o ./ApplicationEngine/WebServerComms.o  ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o  ./AppNodeLinux.o ./GccInlines.o ./main.o   -lpthread -lrt -lm
./TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/MMSConfigData.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [PM100_IEC61850_FW] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: All makefile are automatically generated - 
as main project makefile -

```
################################################################################
    # Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
    ################################################################################

    -include ../makefile.init

    RM := rm -rf

    # All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
    -include sources.mk
    -include Util/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Vendor/scl_main/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/xml/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/tase2/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/tam_task/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/tam/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/stack/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/simulate/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/rtg/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/rfc1006/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/mmsd/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/make7/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/dt/subdir.mk
    -include TMW-61850-Shared/cscl/subdir.mk
    -include Storage/subdir.mk
    -include RulesHandler/subdir.mk
    -include RevenueEvents/subdir.mk
    -include ModbusClient/subdir.mk
    -include Modbus/subdir.mk
    -include Logging/subdir.mk
    -include HAL/subdir.mk
    -include Expat/subdir.mk
    -include EnergyMetering/subdir.mk
    -include DataCollector/subdir.mk
    -include DLMS/subdir.mk
    -include ConfigController/subdir.mk
    -include CalculatedValues/subdir.mk
    -include ApplicationEngine/subdir.mk
    -include .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/subdir.mk
    -include subdir.mk
    -include objects.mk

    ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
    -include $(C_DEPS)
    endif
    endif

    -include ../makefile.defs

    # Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

    # All Target
    all: PM100_IEC61850_FW

    # Tool invocations
    PM100_IEC61850_FW: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
        @echo 'Building target: $@'
        @echo 'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'
        arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  -o "PM100_IEC61850_FW" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
        @echo ' '

    # Other Targets
    clean:
        -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES) PM100_IEC61850_FW
        -@echo ' '

    .PHONY: all clean dependents
    .SECONDARY:

    -include ../makefile.targets
```

Link -  http://txs.io/IA4b - for rest of files

Comment: Could you post your makefile?

Comment: Also try cleaning and recompiling the project. And after cleaning it, make sure there are no `*.o` remaining.

Comment: Eclipse's "Linux GCC" means the default host toolchain, doesn't it? That suggests you have a native (presumably x86) object there, which you'll need to rebuild for ARM with the cross-compiler. Are all those objects built by the same Makefile, or are the problematic ones pulled in from elsewhere?

Comment: @LPs: I had added the make files.

Comment: As @Notlikethat wrote you, you are probably using libs that are not in your arm toolchain. Check all libs and verify that all .o files are cross compiled.

Comment: @suneet add --sysroot flag in compiler & linker settings